# I'm Stumped: How to Send HTML Form using PHP Mailer

Tags: php, html, xampp, localhost, phpmailer

OK, so I have done a substantial amount of research over the last several days and am stumped. I have XAMPP and PHP Mailer and I know they are both working correctly locally.

I also have an HTML form that I know is working correctly using Hostgator web hosting. This HTML form calls a .php file named send_email.php which sends the form contents to my email.

My questions are:

1. What is the new .php code (roughly speaking) to send this HTML form on my local host (XAMPP) using PHP Mailer?
2. How do I call the new .php file in my HTML file?
3. What is the file tree structure that I need for both this HTML form and the new .php file which PHP Mailer will use to send it?

Please note: I've changed some of details in my code so I'm not including my actual email address and person info.

Here is my form:

```
<!-- THE SUBMISSION FORM -->
<div class="container">  

          <form id="contact" action="send_email.php" method="post">

              <h3>Apply Today!</h3>
              <h4></h4>

              <fieldset>
                  <input placeholder="Full Name" type="text" name="name" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                  <input placeholder="Telephone Number" type="tel" name="telephone" tabindex="2" required>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                  <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="email" tabindex="3" required>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                  <input placeholder="Subject" type="text" name="subject" tabindex="4" required>
              </fieldset>
           
              <fieldset>
                  <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." name="message" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
              </fieldset>
            
              <fieldset>
                  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" tabindex="6">Submit</button>
              </fieldset>

          </form> 

</div>
```

Here is the send_email.php file I am using (which I know works)

```html
<?php session_start();    

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $from = "sender@gmail.com";
    $to = "receiver1@gmail.com";
    $to2 = "receiver2@gmail.com";
    $to3 = "receiver3@gmail.com";

    $subject = "NEW LEAD!";
    $message =
    "|---------BEGIN TRANSMISSION----------|" . PHP_EOL . 
    PHP_EOL . "The person that contacted you is: ". $_POST['name'] .
    PHP_EOL . "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] .
    PHP_EOL . "Telephone: " . $_POST['telephone'] .
    PHP_EOL . "Subject: " . $_POST['subject'] .
    PHP_EOL . "Message: " . $_POST['message'] .  PHP_EOL .
    PHP_EOL . "|---------END TRANSMISSION----------|"; 

    $headers = "From:" . $from;

echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will will be in touch.<br/>Go to <a href='/index.php'>Home Page</a>"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    mail($to2, $subject, $message, $headers);
    mail($to3, $subject, $message, $headers);
 } else { 
echo "You must write a message. </br> Please go to <a href='/index.html'>Home Page</a>"; 
}
?>
```

Here is my index.php file in my PHPMAILER folder (which I know works).

```
    <?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    //$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'sender@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'sender-password';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged                                   //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('receiver1@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('receiver2@gmail.com', 'Dylan');     

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

This is my location for PHP Mailer on XAMPP:

```
c:/Users/dylan/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/phpmailer
```

This is the location for my HTML form and send_email.php :

```
c:/Users/dylan/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/WEBSITE
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to change the code at all; it should work equally well wherever it's run from. So long as you're using a sending mechanism that your hosting provider allows, e.g. that they don't block outbound SMTP, it should work fine. Have you tried it?

Aside from that, your file structure looks a bit unusual. Composer installs PHPMailer for you and automatically loads it when you ask for it, so composer is also responsible for where it is stored; you don't need to make your own `phpmailer` folder. If you're hosting a single site, it's probably not necessary to put things in subfolders of your web root, so you can use a flatter structure like:

```
c:/Users/dylan/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/
    index.php
    send_email.php
    vendor/
        composer/
        phpmailer
```

If you are hosting multiple sites you would typically have multiple folders within `.../htdocs/`, each of which will have a similar internal structure.

Answer (score 0):

**You have 0 knowledge of php**

1. **FIRST OF ALL, When you use .php files you can use html in it**
2. **You think this is a joke ?**

```
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    //$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'sender@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'sender-password';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged                                   //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('receiver1@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('receiver2@gmail.com', 'Dylan');     

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

This is copy and pasting to a new LEVEL !

```
$mail->setFrom('receiver1@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('receiver2@gmail.com', 'Dylan');
```

You need to set it up

3. **THE WHOLE CODE IS WRONG!**

   Go to Home Page"; 
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        mail($to2, $subject, $message, $headers);
        mail($to3, $subject, $message, $headers);
     } else { 
    echo "You must write a message.  Please go to Home Page"; 
    }
    ?>

**Last of all**
This is my location for PHP Mailer on XAMPP:

c:/Users/dylan/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/phpmailer

This is the location for my HTML form and send_email.php :

c:/Users/dylan/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/WEBSITE

### ***YOU PUT PHPMAILER IN THE DIRECTORY OF YOU WEB PAGE!!!!!!!1***